# DateTime 25 years back from today

Tags: c#, datetime

in C# how do you calculate date 25 years ago from today?

Comment: Do you mean, how would you calculate the date & time, 25 years ago? :)

Comment: @Yuck Please, not the time! .NET doesn't have complete tables for DST changes, so it could go quite wrongly! (unless you accept to use UTC dates and times)

Comment: 25 years ago they used clay tablets.

Comment: @Henk... Mah... In 1986 there was already the [Olivetti M24](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_M24). I used it and I don't consider myself an ancent sumerian :-)

Comment: @xana I used a M24 too. Clay tablet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about using [`AddYears`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx):

```
DateTime then = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-25);
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-25)
```